# JxBrowser license says license says expired even though it is still new

Tags: java, licensing

Here's a copy of the license

```
Product: JxBrowser
Version: 5.x
Licensed to: JohnDoe
License type: Evaluation
License info: Single-user license
Expiration date: 26-10-2015
Generation date: 26-09-2015
Platforms: mac/x86;win32/x64;mac/x64;linux/x64;mac/ppc;linux/x86;win32/x86
Company: Individual
SigB: i4cjus0qpb50eo5plm3lih92klod0tn5eth9d1dtud3cc61qj18h401pti0591flyem3dnwshmufopgs
SigA: iwz70o2lce7czhwkoiul0xvaf1ntv1bsv9623jmgkbk571fiofk90ow8346su1zltkm8ieajsbi9tdp8
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
JxBrowser license check failed: Your license evaluation period already expired on 23-07-2015. To extend evaluation period please contact sales@teamdev.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found. jar:file:/C:/Users/DELL-PC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/license.jar!/META-INF/teamdev.licenses - Your license evaluation period already expired on 23-07-2015. To extend evaluation period please contact sales@teamdev.com
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at kera.browser.KeraBrowser.main(KeraBrowser.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found. jar:file:/C:/Users/DELL-PC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/license.jar!/META-INF/teamdev.licenses - Your license evaluation period already expired on 23-07-2015. To extend evaluation period please contact sales@teamdev.com
Java Result: 1
```

It says that my license has expired last 23-07-2015. I was able to use it before and perhaps around that date that it says it expired. Could it be connected to registry or something?

Note: Everything has been added properly in the classpath and I've tried more than 10 new licenses. Same error everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not able to make comments on the post. I was faced by a similar issue as well. You can ask for an extended license from TeamDev. It worked for me!

Comment: I was able to do that yesterday and it did work for me too. Thanks for your answer!